# Operations on very large numpy arrays of different dimensions: running waying too slow

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numba, array-broadcasting

Suppose I have two arrays:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.random.rand(500,4,200)
B = np.random.rand(100,100)
```

I would like to do the following operation (in index notation):
C_{ijkmn} = A_{ijk} - B_{mn}

The obvious way to do this is

```
C = A[:,:,:,None,None] - B[None,None,None,:,:] # has shape 500,4,200,100,100
```

But it crashes my kernel and takes up waaay too much memory. So my question is simply how can I go about performing this sort of operation more effeciently? Would numba help? Thanks so much!!

Comment: The `C` shape requires 32 Gb of memory.  Do you have that?

Comment: @hpaulj Well, possibly. I can run this as a job on my local computing cluster

Comment: Computing clusters generally do not share memory between nodes. If you do not have enough memory, the OS will use a slow storage device. Even with enough memory, the computation will be performed out of CPU caches and likely cause slow page-faults. Doing this is not efficient. Why do you want to do that? Do you *really* need the whole C array?

Comment: I would suggest splitting the arrays and doing the process in few iteration loop.

Comment: Numba wont significantly help here. The question is: What do you want to do with this huge (32Gb) C array? Maybe it is just a temporary result, which could be avoided completely or chunk-wise computation is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Welp, turns out the best thing to do here was to calculate a few examples of C and interpolate over fine grid. This seemed to work well! Just using a scipy function...